# shouldoverrideurlloading not called Webview Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

First of all , this post may ,look like a Possible Duplicate of other question, but I have go through many questions but found them not helpful.
Now My problem is that I am loading an URL in my Webview and then I want to Trace URL on each event on webview so I have set up WebviewClient for Webview and overridden shouldoverrideurlloading method, but after first Event , shouldoverrideurlloading not getting called. (worked first time)

Here is the Code I have used :

```
    wvSecurity = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvSecurity);               
    wvSecurity.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wvSecurity.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    wvSecurity.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);     
    wvSecurity.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    wvSecurity.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    wvSecurity.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wvSecurity.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    wvSecurity.loadUrl("URL");

    wvSecurity.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,
                        final String urlStr) {
                    Log.i("URL", "::" + urlStr);
                    return false;
                }
    }
```

**EDIT ::**

Ok, The URL which I want to Trace uses POST method , Now my question is How can I trace POST URL and its data. And one thing , I dont have access to Webpage coming in so I simply cant go for GET method. Please Help !!!

Comment: have you try after returning `true` from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` ?

Comment: Yeah , I tried that did nothing

Comment: I have tried from 8-21 Every API

Comment: @GOLDEE Sorry, misred the docs for that last comment. What kind of request are you making? GET or POST or other? Also, can you put all this info in the question so we don't pollute the comments?

Comment: Actually I dont know much about the Request type @RGraham as this is a Third party Webpage

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I have tried that too

Comment: `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is not called with POST requests - switch on remote debugging & use Chrome to inspect the Network tab to see what requests are going on.

Comment: ohk I will try this , but I dont have much knowledge of Remote Debugging @RGraham

Comment: Is there any to Catch the Post Url ? @RGraham

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess this method gets called when a hyperlink is tapped from page or some redirection happens. So make sure this thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to pass the url in place on "URL" so this will solve your problem.

```
        wvSecurity = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvSecurity);
        wvSecurity.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wvSecurity.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
        wvSecurity.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        wvSecurity.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        wvSecurity.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        wvSecurity.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wvSecurity.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        wvSecurity.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
        wvSecurity.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());



    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            System.out.println("URL :: " + url);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please don't call loadUrl on the url you get from `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` as that callback is also called for subframes with non-https schemes. If you go to a a page like http://jsbin.com/gupug/1/quiet your code will end up calling view.loadUrl('tel:1234') and you will end up showing an error page, since the webview doesn't know how to load a tel: URL.
Instead of calling loadUrl(url) and returning true you should just return false from shouldOverrideUrlLoading.